# Repair Perl Debugger

Tags: perl, debugging

I've been looking at various Perl IDEs lately ([EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org/), [Komodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_IDE), etc.) and most of them require a CPAN module to be installed.  Fair enough, but all the installation seems to have broken the stock debugger (which, for the price, is danged nice).  So now, when I enter the debugger (`perl -d -e 0`), I get errors, and the "restart" seems to give more errors.

How can I repair the installation?

I am using [ActiveState](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveState) Perl, version 5.10.0.

```
> perl -d -e 0

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.3
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `perldoc perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   0

SetConsoleMode failed, LastError=|6| at C:/Perl/lib/Term/ReadKey.pm line 265.
 at C:/Perl/site/lib/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm line 1581
        readline::readline('  DB<1> ') called at C:/Perl/site/lib/Term/ReadLine/
Perl.pm line 11
        Term::ReadLine::Perl::readline('Term::ReadLine::Perl=ARRAY(0x1a9c26c)',
'  DB<1> ') called at C:/Perl/lib/perl5db.pl line 6414
        DB::readline('  DB<1> ') called at C:/Perl/lib/perl5db.pl line 2227
        DB::DB called at -e line 1
  DB<1> R
Warning: some settings and command-line options may be lost!
Your vendor has not defined POSIX macro _SC_OPEN_MAX, used at C:/Perl/lib/perl5d
b.pl line 3320
 at C:/Perl/lib/POSIX.pm line 56
        POSIX::AUTOLOAD() called at C:/Perl/lib/perl5db.pl line 3320
        DB::DB called at -e line 1
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.

  DB<1>
```

Comment: Komodo never required to install anything from CPAN. Easiest would be to uninstall ActivePerl, delete `C:\Perl` and install ActivePerl again. Also, you should never use CPAN under ActivePerl - use `ppm install` instead

Comment: Sorry, I was imprecise.  I do use ppm... But it accesses CPAN, correct?

Comment: `ppm` does not use or directly access CPAN. ppm/ppd packages may be built by repository maintainers using grabbing source from CPAN, but after package is built, CPAN is no longer in picture

Comment: [Realizing this is an old question,] Does the [`set TERM=dumb`](http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-win32-users/14525/) fix not work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Komodo, but I did remember reading something about the Perl debugger having problems with [Epic/Eclipse IDE](http://www.epic-ide.org/faq.php#debug) this the issue?

There's nothing in the EPIC documentation that states you must install a particular module for EPIC to work. I'd be surprised if you must install a module for Komodo since it's ActiveState's own IDE.

You can use CPAN with ActivePerl. However, you will need to install `nmake` or CPAN's `dmake` and maybe a C compiler depending upon the module. It's documented [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.16/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#CPAN_shell). ActiveState, however recommends you use the PPM utility since it already has everything compiled for you.

You can also try Strawberry Perl instead of Active State. Strawberry Perl already includes the entire MinGW environment, so it's guaranteed to be 100% compatible with the Unix version and all CPAN modules.

Comment: I got EPIC working... I just hate the idea of starting Eclipse (which takes longer to start up than it does to write the perl script in the first place) and creating a friggin' project for every little thing.

Comment: @mswanberg What did you have to do to get EPIC to work? Was it that Cwd.pm bug? I never used Komodo and don't know anyone who has, so I don't know if there's a similar issue with Komodo. Sorry. My IDE of choice for Perl is VIM. It does everything I need like Syntax highlighting, the ability to look up information in Perldoc via Shift-K, and most importantly, make me look Uber-Geek when compared to those script kiddies who can't write a lick of code unless they have their IDE hold their hands. Real developers use text based terminal windows and archaic commands! Now, where's my Jolt Cola?

Comment: Well, there's a difference between an IDE and a programming editor.  A true IDE will allow break points, display of variable contents, etc.  I mostly use Notepad++. As for EPIC, who knows?  I was trying a ton of stuff.  But in the end, you have to create a project and Import your script(s).  Komodo is far better... it's just $295!

Answer (score 1):

I know of two places that non-standard Perl debugging libraries can be activated at.

Check your environment. You may have PERLDB_OPTS set. Setting this to "null" will (temporarily) disable them and restore the standard Perl debugger.

Check your registry. You may have the PERL5DB key set somewhere. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Perl would be typical, especially if one of the debuggers you were testing was the old ActiveState PDK Graphical Debugger.

Changing both may be necessary to permanently switch back to the native debugger.

I can confirm [David W.'s statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106093/repair-perl-debugger/14107274#14107274) that Komodo IDE will not require you to install anything from CPAN (or from PPM for that matter).

Comment: Good information.  None of this was the case for me, unfortunately.  I've uninstalled the various IDEs I was trying and that's helped.  The perl -d debugger seems to work now except that it chokes when I try to restart the program.  I did a reinstall of perl 5.10.0 which gave me a "repair" option, which I tried.  Didn't help.  I am loathe to uninstall perl and reinstall from scratch, but it may be the way to go.  Either that, or I can just keep debugging the old way... warn this, warn that, look at the STDERR output.  Komodo looks solid... but I don't have $295 that I'm not using.